# How to update the value by calling function recursively using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, object

for given arrayobject `listarray` and passing `updatevalue` as parameter,

note: `first larger value is will be first greater value of updatevalue`

update the value `updatevalue` to first larger value then

second larger value to add updatevalue plus 1 and then third larger value to add plus 2 and so on

How to do using for...of javascript

```
example 1
let updatevalue = 2
const listarray =[
  {id:17, value: 4},
  {id:12, value: null},
  {id:33, value: 3},
  {id:45, value: 5},
]

Expected Output

// first larger value is 3 -> becomes 2
// second larger value is 4 -> updateval + 1 -> 2+1 -> 3
// third larger value is 5 -> updateval + 2 -> 2+2 -> 4

[
  {id:17, value: 3},
  {id:12, value: null},
  {id:33, value: 2},
  {id:45, value: 4},
]

*******

example 2
let updatevalue = 3
const listarray =[
  {id:17, value: 7},
  {id:12, value: null},
  {id:33, value: 10},
  {id:45, value: 5},
  {id:18, value: 4},
]

ExpectedOutput

[
  {id:17, value: 5},
  {id:12, value: null},
  {id:33, value: 6},
  {id:45, value: 4},
  {id:18, value: 3},
]

******
```

```
for (let item of listarray) {
  if (item > prevValue) {
 ...item,
 val: prevValue + 1;

 }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by *first larger value*?

Comment: @DecPK , first largervalue is the parameter `updatevalue` > the first greater value in the listarr,

Comment: for the example, updatevalue = 2, updatevalue > first greater value in the list so it will be {id:33, value: 3} which i set {id:33, value: 2}

Comment: So according to this case, first object `{ id: 17, value: 4 }` should be the first larger value where `updatevalue > the first greater value`

Comment: @DecPK, i wrote 2 examples in the question, i think misunderstood

Comment: @DecPK, in the example1, first larger value is will be first greater value of `updateValue` so, {id:33, value: 3}

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateValuesInPlace(arr, updateVal) {
    let increment = 1;
    let currentLargestVal = updateVal

    while (true) {
        // Find the smallest number larger than currentLargestVal
        let minVal = Infinity;
        let minIndex = -1;

        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].value !== null && arr[i].value > currentLargestVal && arr[i].value < minVal) {
                minVal = arr[i].value;
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }

        // If there's no number larger than currentLargestVal, break the loop
        if (minIndex === -1) break;

        // Update the value
        arr[minIndex].value = updateVal + increment;

        // Prepare for the next loop
        currentLargestVal = minVal;
        increment++;
    }

    return arr;
}

let listArray = [
  {id:17, value: 7},
  {id:12, value: null},
  {id:33, value: 10},
  {id:45, value: 5},
  {id:18, value: 4},
]

updateValuesInPlace(listArray, 2);
console.log(listArray)
```

[image]